# changing text color associate with different comment modes

Tags: color, comments

in my set up file I have defined different redaction modes (as comment) as follows:

```
\newcounter{redmode}
\setcounter{redmode}{\redactionmode}
\includecomment{rd1}    
\includecomment{rd2}    
\newcommand{\redact}{
  \ifcase\number\value{redmode}
    \excludecomment{rd1}
    \excludecomment{rd2}

  \or
    \includecomment{rd1}
    \excludecomment{rd2}
 \or
    \excludecomment{rd1}
    \includecomment{rd2}
\else
    \includecomment{rd1}
    \includecomment{rd2}
  \fi
}
\redact
```

my question is, how can I also assign different colors to each mode? for example if in my main.tex document I am commenting in mode rd1 the text color is red automatically.

Thanks for any help you could provide.

Comment: Use a custom colour name and define it in your `\ifcase` statement with `\definecolor` or `\colorlet`. Please note that you don't need `\numexpr` if all you're doing is `\value{<counter>}` for `\ifcase`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. when I add the \definecolor or \textcolor in if case statements the color will not be displayed. I have wrote it as :
    \excludecomment{rd1}
    \excludecomment{rd2}
     \textcolor{\blue}{}                                                                                                          it would be greate if you could give me an example. Thanks again